# Forward RTSP/HTTP Video Stream to a new HTTPS stream

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, video-streaming, ip-camera

I'm currently prototyping an extension to a React Native iOS-only building management app to allow the IP CCTV video streams of particular buildings to be viewed on the fly by logged in users with sufficient permission.

The issue is, I am currently using `React-Native-Video` as the.video player component, but it only accepts HTTPS links (Apple App Transport Security) and the camera video URL's aren't SSL encrypted.

To enhance the security, I was wondering if it'd be possible to "convert" these unprotected streams into a new HTTP video stream once the app requests it for a specific camera on a dedicated API. I want the new stream to come through my SSL protected domain for this particular service, presumably by the endpoint route hit by the client app.

Essentially, when the iOS app hits for example `/view-camera` and POSTs valid authorisation and a camera reference, it would begin to "copy" the data from the less secure RTSP/HTTP stream URL stored in the DB for that camera entry and output it into a new output stream (returning data either over a socket of some kind) that would pass through my own domain.

`Existing HTTP stream -> API <- > iOS app.`

I've got the API set up in HapiJS with the necessary middleware/authentication (handled by a separate auth API service), and the next piece is handling the transcoding of the video streams which honestly is something I am completely new to. I expect that I won't be able to return this video data via the same POST request that initiated this process, perhaps if it can provide a new URL specific to that camera.

I came across a Node package called [`stream-transcoder.js`](https://github.com/trenskow/stream-transcoder.js) and it "seems" to do what I need, but does anybody know of any others I can try out?

I hope I have explained this sufficiently, any input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure how to help with the HTTPS conversion except to suggest trying out my company, [Mux](https://mux.com) as an option. The live streaming API (including the transcoding piece) is in beta and I can get you in early to see if it does what you need. It can take RTMP as input and output HLS over HTTPS. Email me at steve at mux.com.